# Following JS Code not working for .length attribute in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, string-length

```
let isValidPassword = function (password) {
    if (password.length <= 8 && password.includes('password')) {
        console.log('Password is not according to Company Policy.');
    } else {
        console.log('Password is accepatble!');
    }
}
isValidPassword();
```

Here password.length is not working.

Error is :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at isValidPassword (C:\Users\Gitanshu Choudhary\Desktop\modern_js\hello_earth.js:163:18)
    at Object. (C:\Users\Gitanshu Choudhary\Desktop\modern_js\hello_earth.js:169:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11

Comment: You call `isValidPassword()` without any arguments. Hence, `password` is undefined.

Comment: call `isValidPassword('you password')`

Answer (score 4):

You're also making one mistake here which is `&&`, you mean here if the password is less than 8 and also must exists the password string in it, it will give you the correct result, otherwise wrong. if both is true, the code will be executed, however it is false.

```
true && true // true
true && false // false
```

here is the correct result:

```js
let isValidPassword = function (password) {
    if (password.length <= 8 || password.includes('password') ) {
        console.log('Password is not according to Company Policy.');
    } else {
        console.log('Password is accepatble!');
    }
}
isValidPassword('passwordkksk');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass some parameter while calling the Function.

In your case it should be something like :

```
isValidPassword('password');
```

OR using variable

```
let pass = 'abc@123';
isValidPassword(pass)
```